# Hide shipping & handling value in the multishipping overview

Tags: magento2, php, shipping, multishipping

When i do **multishipping checkout**, there will be showed `Shipping & Handling` value in each of footer total of each adrresses like in the picture below. Is there a way to hide it? Since in my case, the shipping is always free.

[image: Shipping & handling]